# Where's the page cache store?

Tags: memory

When I learn how the `read` file work , I know kernel first copy disk data to page cache , then copy from page cache to user space .

I don't understand where's the page cache store ? Is it a mapping physical memory address to disk address by page table ?

Comment: Hello @shaoyihe This is very broad subject. I encourage you to review this link https://manybutfinite.com/post/page-cache-the-affair-between-memory-and-files/ they had illustrated all what you need to know about page cache. For simplicity purposes page cache is stored in "unused areas of memory". more valuable links are below in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux, the page cache accelerates many accesses to files on non volatile storage. This happens because, when it first reads from or writes to data media like hard drives, Linux also stores data in *unused areas of memory*, which acts as a cache. If this data is read again later, it can be quickly read from this cache in memory.

More [1](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Linux_Page_Cache_Basics) [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) [3](https://manybutfinite.com/post/page-cache-the-affair-between-memory-and-files/)